# Redefining String as class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I have to redefine String as class and have issue with either operator+ overloading or copying constructor. My main() compiles but gives nothing or doodles in return. Here is fragment of class String:

```
class String {
  char *nap;
  public:

  String(const char* ns){
    nap=strcpy(new char[strlen(ns)+1],ns);
  }
  String(const String & n){
    nap=strcpy(new char[strlen(n.nap)+1],n.nap);
  }
  String operator+(const String& n) const;
  String operator+(const char* ns) const;

  //operator=
  String& operator=(const String &n){
      if(this==&n)
        return *this;
  delete []nap;
  nap= strcpy(new char[strlen(n.nap)+1],n.nap);
  return *this;
  }
  //...
  friend String operator+(const char*, const String&);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const String&);
  };

 String String::operator+(const String& s) const{
 return String(nap+*s.nap);
}
String String:: operator+(const char* c) const{
return String(nap+*c);
}
 String operator+(const char* c,const String & s){
 return String(String(s)+String(c));
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream& os,const String& s){
 os<<s.nap<<endl;
 return os;
}
```

And here is main:

```
String s ="To "+String("be ") + "or not to be";
cout<<s<<endl;
```

Comment: With this `nap+*s.nap` you are not concatenating strings but you add an offset to a pointer to char `(char *)`. The value you add is the integer value of the first character pointed to by `s.nap`. The resulting pointer is used to construct a new String. Since this points to "somewhere" in memory you end up with a junk string (or a memory violation)...

Comment: Hey, first thanks for quick response. Second, i wrote something like that String String:: operator+(const char* c) const{
 return String(strcpy(new char[strlen(c)+1], c));
} is that what you meant? and if so, how can I link those strings in friend operator+? Unfortunately I am quite fresh with this language

Comment: See full example down below. You seem to come more from a _JAVAish_ background. Keep in mind that in C++ you're fully responsible for memory management unless you use special wrappers for pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class String {
  char *nap;

public:
  // Default argument is nifty !!
  String(const char* ns=""){
    nap=strcpy(new char[strlen(ns)+1],ns);
  }
  // !! Don'te forget to delete[] on destruction
  ~String() {
      delete[] nap;
  }

  String(const String & n){
    nap=strcpy(new char[strlen(n.nap)+1],n.nap);
  }

  String operator+(const String& n) const;

  // Not necessary since String(const char *) exists
  // an expression like String+"X" will be casted to String+String("X")

  // String operator+(const char* ns) const;

  //operator=
  String& operator=(const String &n){
      if(this==&n)
        return *this;
      delete []nap;
      nap= strcpy(new char[strlen(n.nap)+1],n.nap);
      return *this;
  }

  //...
  friend String operator+(const char*, const String&);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const String&);
  };
 // Make enough space for both strings
 // concatenate
 // !! delete the buffer  
 String String::operator+(const String& si) const {
    char *n = new char [strlen(nap)+strlen(si.nap)+1];
    strcpy(n,nap);
    strcpy(n+strlen(nap),si.nap);
    String so = String(n);
    delete [] n;
    return so;
 }

// Not necessary. Since String(const char *) exists
// String String:: operator+(const char* c) const{
// return String(nap+*c);
// }

String operator+(const char* c,const String & s){
 return String(String(s)+String(c));
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& os,const String& s){
 os<<s.nap<<std::endl;
 return os;
}
```

Comment: One last thing, if you would be so kind as to exlpain why and what does strcpy(n+strlen(nap),si.nap); do. I am confused about this strlen(nap) thing.

Comment: it appends si.nap after n+stren(nap). Your current buffer is `n` You already copied `nap`into `n` and now you have to copy `si.nap` after the copy of `nap`.

Answer (score 1):

Call [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) (or better [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/)) in your operator+ instead of adding pointers.
Or do it yourself by copying the bytes of one nap to the end another nap.
In both cases, you must assure that there is enough memory allocated!

Answer (score 1):

The addition operators look incorrect to me.

The `*` operator can be read as *the contents of*. So `*s.nap` is actually the contents of `s.nap` which is a `char` representing first character pointed to by `nap`. So `nap+*s.nap` is not what you want, neither is `nap+*c`.

You also need a destructor for your class to ensure that the memory `nap` points to is deleted.